How to get Incoming call phone number in android 14
I want to get incoming caller number , i used a BroadcastReceiver  , i use this method and have no problem :
getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER) 
, but i get warning from android studio that this method is not usable in android 14 and above.
This is onReceive method :
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    val state = intent?.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            Debug.logInfo("Phone is ringing ...")
        incomingCallerNumber = intent?.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        incomingCallerNumber = "0"+incomingCallerNumber?.substringAfter('8')
        if (incomingCallerNumber != "0null") {
            Debug.logInfo("incomingCallerNumber : $incomingCallerNumber")
            Debug.logInfo("Context : $context")
        }
    }
}

How can i do this in android 14 and handle both versions in my code?

Quoting the documentation: "Companion apps for wearable devices should use the InCallService API to retrieve the phone number for calls instead. Apps performing call screening should use the CallScreeningService API instead." If what you want to build does not fit either of those patterns, it would appear that you will need to do without that particular value on newer versions of Android.
